# Replace start date for a given set of csv date data using panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, date

python beginner here, I have a csv file that has one year data, starting at 1/1/2000, I am trying to convert the start date of the data to a specified date, 26/08/2020.
The code I currently have replaces the date but it starts 1/1/2020 instead of 26/08/2020

```
startdate = pd.to_datetime(startdate, dayfirst = True)
data[date] = pd.to_datetime(data[date])
data[date] = [f.replace(year = startdate.year) for f in data[date]]
data = data.set_index(date)
data = data.astype('float')
```

and I was wondering if there is a way to match the start date with the given data set, so if my start date is in 1/8/2018, I start replacing data from the csv file from 1/8/2000, so the final date range will be from 1/8/2018 to 31/8/2019.

Input:

01/01/2000 00:000

01/01/2000 01:000

.........

31/12/2000 23:000

Expected output

26/08/2018 00:000

26/08/2018 01:000

.
.
.
.
.

26/08/2019 23:000

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I dont understand what your input looks like or what your expected output is can you show some of your input and what you would expect for that specific input set

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.to_datetime(timestamps,day_first=True) + datetime.timedelta(days=664249)
```

I believe would give you want you want  ... just offset it by the difference in dates

Answer (score 0):

Somethin' like that:

```
import pandas as pd

date_old = pd.to_datetime("01/01/2000 00:000")
date_new = pd.to_datetime("26/08/2018 00:000")

delta = date_new - date_old

days = 366

result = [date_old + delta + pd.Timedelta(days=days) for day in range(days)]
```